# Extend PickerViews Component while touching

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView with a variable number of components to display. In its contoller i have this `-pickerView:withForComponent:`

```
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pv widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    CGFloat f;
    if (component == 0) {
        f = 30;

    } else {
        if ([componentsData count]>2) {
            f = 260.0/([componentsData count]-1);
        } else{
            f = 260.0;
        }
    } 
    return f;
}
```

this works fine if I call `[pickerView reloadAllComponents]`, but how could I extend a components width if it is touched (and of course shrink all others)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, even if your picker options are all text, you'll have to use

```
pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:
```

You'll basically need to generate an array of UIViews for your picker options, and retain them in an array.  Then, when a row is selected, expand that UIView directly, and iterate through the array, contracting the others accordingly.